# Error in Variable initialization during compile time in java

Tags: java

I have Java two programs.

Program  One

```
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {

        double price = 10;
        String model;
        if (price > 10)
            model = "Smartphone";
        else if (price <= 10)
            model = "landline";
            System.out.println(model);
    }
}
```

Output :- variable model might not have been initialized(Error)

Program Two:-

```
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
           double area = 10.98;
           String color;
           if (area < 5)
               color = "red";
           else
               color = "blue";
           System.out.println(color);
    }
}
```

Output:- blue

My question here is since both the programs are almost similar, why am I getting variable might not have been initialized ?

If the first program is having the problem, should not the 2nd program also throw the same error ?

Comment: color will always be initialized, model will be initialized only if something, that's how the compiler sees it.

Answer (score 4):

**Compiler is smart enough.**

In second case you full fill all the conditions. There is an else part to save after all the conditions.

But in your first case there is no else part. Which mean if no conditions is pass, you have a blank field there.

You must either provide an else which make sure the initialization part

```
double price = 10;
        String model;
        if (price > 10)
            model = "Smartphone";
        else if (price <= 10)
            model = "landline";
        else
           model = null
```

or provide a default value null or as you want.

```
double price = 10;
        String model =null;
        if (price > 10)
            model = "Smartphone";
        else if (price <= 10)
            model = "landline";
```

Answer (score 4):

In the first case, change the `else if` to just `else`. The Java compiler isn't smart enough to realize that one of the two conditions will 100% be executed.

Comment: +1 for Java compiler isn't smart enough to realize that one of the two conditions will 100% be executed.

Comment: Compiler is smart. That's why it created an error to make sure that there is always an initialization part.

Answer (score 2):

In the first code snippet, although logically speaking either the `if` or the `else` must occur, the Java compiler does not "know" this.  It presumes that it might be possible for *both* `if` statements to fail, and therefore gives you a warning message.  Here is a breakdown of what is happening in the code:

```
double price = 10;
String model;
if (price > 10)
    model = "Smartphone";
else if (price <= 10)           // the Java compiler doesn't "know" that one
    model = "landline";         // of these two cases will always occur
    System.out.println(model);
```

If you change the code to the following you will not get this warning anymore:

```
double price = 10;
String model;
if (price > 10)
    model = "Smartphone";
else {
    model = "landline";         // in case the if fails, this else will ALWAYS
    System.out.println(model);  // happen, so 'model' is guaranteed to get
}                               // intiailized
```

In your second code snippet, you use an explicit `if-else` for initialization, the compiler therefore remains silent on this point.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that, in your first program you can see that you have used an `if-else if` statement, the **compiler can’t be sure** whether these conditions will evaluate to true or false, **resulting in non initialization of the variable**,hence you get the error.

But in your 2nd program you can see, you have used if-else statement, so in this case, the compiler knows, if the if condition does not satisfy then it(the compiler) can execute the else statement and give the value to the varaible.

So just put this in your 1st program

```
String model;
if (price > 10)
model = "Smartphone";
else 
model = "landline";
System.out.println(model);
```

*I removed the if part of else-if* just so that you know what I did

Answer (score 1):

In the first case you need to initialize since if both the conditions are false (if and else if ) then what would be the default value to be displayed.
Add an else part in ur first code and it would not give such warning.

In the second case when the first part (if (condition) == false) then else part will be executed and hence there is no such condition under which the variable color won't have any value.

Answer (score 0):

> My question here is since both the programs are almost similar, why am
>   I getting variable might not have been initialized ?

Actually they are not same. You are having a field name `model` which is not initialized like:

```
String model = null;
```

Compiler is considering the case when it is not initialized by any of your if conditions and that is why it is complaining. In first case `else` is missing.